# Mount Office 365 OneDrive in OS X Finder

Tags: onedrive, macos

Is it possible to mount my Office 365 account's OneDrive in Finder? Maybe there is a protocol that OneDrive supports that would allow this to work? WebDAV?

Answer (score 2):

There's an app for that. Check out OneDrive for Mac.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/onedrive/id823766827